# Do I have to use a integer auto-inc primary key with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database table which has over 35 million rows. I originally created an id field as the primary key. But this id field was just an `auto_increment` value which was not part of my data. But my main queries would be on a field called zipcode.

Queries made with `WHERE zipcode=''` seem to be very slow. I realised that indexing the zipcode field speeds this up. However, I have then noticed that each field that is indexed takes up certain amount of space. The indexing the zipcode fieled only takes up 75MB but the "id" field primary key index takes up over 3GB.

As I do not use the "id" field for anything, I have now removed the id field and just keeping the index on the zipcode field. I just felt that the id field was taking up space for no reason. Is there any disadvantages of not having a unique id field?

Any other ways I can speed up queries to this database table?

Comment: if u attach your table columns list that would be more helpful :)

Comment: I've removed one of your tags: MySQL != SQL Server (the latter is a Microsoft product).

Comment: Is your zipcode field now declared as `PRIMARY`? Rows should always be uniquely identifiable with a primary key (but it does not have to be integer or auto-increment).

Comment: @halfer no the zipcode field is not the primary key, it's just indexed. It cannot be the primary key because each zipcode value has on average of 25 records records associated to it.

Comment: Right, I'd stick with having a primary key then. [Read more here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=should+tables+always+have+a+primary+key).

Comment: Well, if a zipcode can change, the id is important.

Comment: ok, so you would recommend putting the id field back with unique auto_increment values even though i wont use it as part of my data?

Answer (score 1):

There are some significant advantages to be had by maintaining a primary key, even a so-called surrogate primary key like an autoincremented `id` column.

For one thing, it lets you edit your table if you need to using tools like phpMyadmin or MySQL workbench.  If there's no primary key, those tools can't update your table.

For another thing, in InnoDB the primary key is a tacit part of every index, so operations using indexes get faster. For example, if you want to find the entries in your table with the top populations, you could do this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabl t
  JOIN ( SELECT ID
           FROM tabl
          ORDER BY population DESC
          LIMIT 10
       )  s ON s.ID = t.ID
```

If you index `population` and you have a primary key, this will be very fast, for example.

You say your `ID` index consumes 3GB. Rounding up, a 1TB disk drive costs US$100. So, your 3GB of index are using US$0.30 worth of resources.  Saving the space is a false optimization.

Don't delete the primary key.